# Adding a imagebutton to the layout of a custom item in a ListView stops receiving the long pressed event

Tags: android, listview, layout, long-press

I'm making a listview with custom adapter / custom item layout (2x TextViews and 4x ImageButtons) and i want to be able to long press the list item to do something and still be able to press the ImageButtons on the layout.

The problem is that if i just have TextViews it works and catches the Long press event, as soon as i add an ImageButton the Long press event stops working. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try making the `ImageButton` non-focusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add clickable views (like buttons) in your item layout they catch the click event and it doesn't bubble to the underlying `ListView`, to fix this you can add the long click listener to the items' root layout.

So instead of doing this in your activity:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);
```

you do this in your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    view.setLongClickable(true);
    view.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: That apparently worked, will do more tests to see if it really meets my needs, thanks :)

Comment: Glad to be of service. I had the exact same problem a while ago but this is the only solution i found. Please let me know if you find something else :)